# Determine date from the given time in php

Tags: php, date, time

if shop open time is from 14:00pm to 2:00am (morning of next day ). how it will determine the date of next day of time 4:00pm.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$start = strtotime('2016-03-01 14:00:00'); // it is evening time
$end = strtotime('? 02:00:00'); // it is morning time of next day
if(time() >= $start && time() <= $end)
{ echo "okay";}
else
{echo "not okay";}
```

how it will determine the date in place of '?' in above code.

Comment: I am bit confused: 14:00pm does not really exist. You mean 02:00pm - right? Then, your question is not really clear. Do you mean `strtotime( "tomorrow 02:00:00", $start )`?

Comment: yes ! start time is 2 pm and end time is  2 am on next day . how it will determine date when 2 am occurs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had almost the solution. You can get it very simple with the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$start = strtotime('2016-03-01 14:00:00');     // it is evening time
$end = strtotime('tomorrow 02:00:00', $start); // it is morning time of next day
```